# Forms for polymorphically associated resources where a basic resource path "/resource" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic resource `Location` that can latch on to, let's say, instances of `Store`. The extent to which this "should" be a polymorphic resource is questionable, but that's besides the point at the moment.

A location accesses its polymorphic parent via `location.locatable`.

Since the location will always be the child of a resource like a store, I'd like to remove the route to `POST /locations` and instead have the application direct POST requests to `/stores/1/locations`.

Now, the default Rails method when it comes to dealing with polymorphic associations is to do it at the controller level with

```
def new
  @location = Store.find(params[:store_id]).vendors.new
end
```

This, as expected, prepopulates `location.locatable_id` and `location.locatable_type`. Wonderful. But it still routes to `locations_path` by default, which I would like to get rid of.

And I try, it raises a route not found error.

So how can I prepare a general `location` form that is extensible to new parents?

I have come to the following:

```
form_for(@location, :url => [@location.locatable, @location]) do |l|
```

Which seems to work fine, but the passing of a path as an array irks me, and for some reason I can't find any [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for) on the subject. Is there a better way to accomplish this? I'm new-ish to polymorphic resources, and it would be nice to do this right from the start.

---

Also, a (quite) minor peripheral issue is that this doesn't cooperate out of the box with the default RSpec-generated view spec since Rails actually tries to find `@location.locatable`. This is fairly easy to get around though. I was planning on rewriting the view spec from top to bottom anyway.